# EditText in LinearLayout streches to full screen in run-time when the root ViewGroup is ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout

I have a TabLayout with ViewPager2 and I set these in my main activity layout. in a different layout I have the fragment related layout, the one that the main activity hosts.

The problem is that in run-time the EditText streches to full screen when I click on it or when there're items to be populated in the RecyclerView , even without clicking on the EditText.

Layout when RecyclerView is empty and I don't click on the EditText:

[image: Before clicking on EditText]

After clicking on the EditText:

[image: After clicking on the EditText:]

Before I will paste here the code. You will notice in the code that the height of the LinearLayout is wrap_content, but that doesn't matter since for any height I will set it the problem will occur. Also, attribute

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight
```

or any variation of it will not solve the problem. However, if the root ViewGroup is RelativeLayout then problem is solved.

Now, the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_viewgroup_fragment_chat"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/color_chat"
tools:context=".ChatFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_chat"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<!-- A horizontal line between the chatbox and RecyclerView -->
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#dfdfdf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/message_interface_layout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_interface_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_edittext"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/hint_edittext_chat"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
        android:text="@string/chat_send_message"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: LInear layout width is  `android:layout_width="0dp"` change to wrap_content

Comment: @ShaluTD this has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: set a static width on the edit text like Android:layout_width = 100dp

Answer (score 0):

try this
I think that may help you

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_viewgroup_fragment_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_chat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- A horizontal line between the chatbox and RecyclerView -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#dfdfdf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/message_edittext"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="message "
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/send_message_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/send_message_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="send message"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that having problem with screen resize. I search all over stackoverflow and didn't find any solution. I saw everywhere to use window soft mode with "adjustPan" or "adjustResize" or any variations or these.

The problem was that I used app theme with no ActionBar and I implemented my own ToolBar.

The solution was to use default app themes that AppCompat or MaterialComponents provide.